# Calculate number of points with expected values

Tags: probability, expected-value

**The Problem**

Lets say you have a game where using an item gives you a certain number of points, with different probabilities for each point value. The probabilities are unknown, but can be estimated from a sample. From a sample of ~200 item uses, I obtain the following counts:

\begin{array}{ll}
&\text{Points}      &\text{Count} \\
\hline
&\text{1}  &\text{115}  \\
&\text{2}  &\text{56}  \\
&\text{3}  &\text{24}  \\
&\text{5}  &\text{4}  \\
&\text{8}  &\text{2}  \\
\end{array}

As this is only a sample, it's unknown whether the game ever assigns 4, 6, or 7 points. The goal is to reach 2888 points in total. How many items do you need to use?

**My Solution**

I started by calculating the probability mass function of the random variable $X$ by dividing the count by the total:

\begin{array}{ll}
&\text{Points}      &\text{Mass} \\
\hline
&\text{1}  &\text{0.572}  \\
&\text{2}  &\text{0.279}  \\
&\text{3}  &\text{0.119}  \\
&\text{5}  &\text{0.020}  \\
&\text{8}  &\text{0.010}  \\
\end{array}

From this I can calculate the expected value of $X$:
$$
x = \{1,2,3,5,8\} \\
E[X] = \sum_{i=1}^{5} x_i P(X = x_i) \\
E[X] = (1 \times 0.572) + (2 \times 0.279) + (3 \times 0.119) + (5 \times 0.020) + (8 \times 0.010) \\
E[X] = 1.667
$$

Then the total number of items you need to use is simply $2888 / 1.667 = 1732.8$

I have only recently started learning probability so I'm wondering:

1. Is this a correct approach/solution to the problem? Is expected value the correct concept here, rather than simply the mean, given I'm dealing with a sample?
2. Is my use of notation/terminology correct?
3. How do you handle the fact that it's unknown whether 4, 6, 7 points can be given? I'm thinking another approach might be to find the closest fitting function/distribution and calculate the expected value directly from that - would that be a valid approach and what would it look like?

Comment: Looks good. As for point 3, you may try to fit a binomial model to your data.

Comment: Is expected value the correct concept here, rather than simply the mean, given I'm dealing with a sample?

Comment: The expected value here is the same as the weighted average.